# Inno Setup custom page

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to create a custom wizard page after the page where you select the install location.

I have seen how to create custom pages and add them to the wizard in the `InitializeWizard` procedure.

My problem is that when I create a custom page the default page for install location selection does not appear any more.

What options do I have to keep the default page(install location selection) and also add a my new custom page?

Thanks

My code looks something like this (CodeClasses.iss example provided by inno ):

```
procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  Button, FormButton: TButton;
  CheckBox: TCheckBox;
  Edit: TEdit;
  PasswordEdit: TPasswordEdit;
  Memo: TMemo;
  Lbl, ProgressBarLabel: TLabel;
  ComboBox: TComboBox;
  ListBox: TListBox;
  StaticText: TNewStaticText;
  ProgressBar: TNewProgressBar;
  CheckListBox, CheckListBox2: TNewCheckListBox;
  FolderTreeView: TFolderTreeView;
  BitmapImage, BitmapImage2, BitmapImage3: TBitmapImage;
  BitmapFileName: String;
  RichEditViewer: TRichEditViewer;
begin
  { TButton and others }

  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TButton and others');

  Button := TButton.Create(Page);
  Button.Width := ScaleX(75);
  Button.Height := ScaleY(23);
  Button.Caption := 'TButton';
  Button.OnClick := @ButtonOnClick;
  Button.Parent := Page.Surface;

  CheckBox := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
  CheckBox.Top := Button.Top + Button.Height + ScaleY(8);
  CheckBox.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  CheckBox.Height := ScaleY(17);
  CheckBox.Caption := 'TCheckBox';
  CheckBox.Checked := True;
  CheckBox.Parent := Page.Surface;

  Edit := TEdit.Create(Page);
  Edit.Top := CheckBox.Top + CheckBox.Height + ScaleY(8);
  Edit.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth div 2 - ScaleX(8);
  Edit.Text := 'TEdit';
  Edit.Parent := Page.Surface;

  PasswordEdit := TPasswordEdit.Create(Page);
  PasswordEdit.Left := Page.SurfaceWidth - Edit.Width;
  PasswordEdit.Top := CheckBox.Top + CheckBox.Height + ScaleY(8);
  PasswordEdit.Width := Edit.Width;
  PasswordEdit.Text := 'TPasswordEdit';
  PasswordEdit.Parent := Page.Surface;

  Memo := TMemo.Create(Page);
  Memo.Top := Edit.Top + Edit.Height + ScaleY(8);
  Memo.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  Memo.Height := ScaleY(89);
  Memo.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
  Memo.Text := 'TMemo';
  Memo.Parent := Page.Surface;

  Lbl := TLabel.Create(Page);
  Lbl.Top := Memo.Top + Memo.Height + ScaleY(8);
  Lbl.Caption := 'TLabel';
  Lbl.AutoSize := True;
  Lbl.Parent := Page.Surface;

  FormButton := TButton.Create(Page);
  FormButton.Top := Lbl.Top + Lbl.Height + ScaleY(8);
  FormButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
  FormButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  FormButton.Caption := 'TSetupForm';
  FormButton.OnClick := @FormButtonOnClick;
  FormButton.Parent := Page.Surface;
```

......

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  AboutButton, CancelButton: TButton;
  URLLabel: TNewStaticText;
  BackgroundBitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  BackgroundBitmapText: TNewStaticText;
begin
  { Custom wizard pages }

  CreateTheWizardPages;

  { Other custom controls }

  CancelButton := WizardForm.CancelButton;

  AboutButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AboutButton.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - CancelButton.Left - CancelButton.Width;
  AboutButton.Top := CancelButton.Top;
  AboutButton.Width := CancelButton.Width;
  AboutButton.Height := CancelButton.Height;
  AboutButton.Caption := '&About...';
  AboutButton.OnClick := @AboutButtonOnClick;
  AboutButton.Parent := WizardForm;

  URLLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  URLLabel.Caption := 'www.innosetup.com';
  URLLabel.Cursor := crHand;
  URLLabel.OnClick := @URLLabelOnClick;
  URLLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  { Alter Font *after* setting Parent so the correct defaults are inherited first }
  URLLabel.Font.Style := URLLabel.Font.Style + [fsUnderline];
  URLLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
  URLLabel.Top := AboutButton.Top + AboutButton.Height - URLLabel.Height - 2;
  URLLabel.Left := AboutButton.Left + AboutButton.Width + ScaleX(20);

  BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundBitmapImage.Left := 50;
  BackgroundBitmapImage.Top := 90;
  BackgroundBitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
  BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap;
  BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := MainForm;

  BackgroundBitmapText := TNewStaticText.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundBitmapText.Left := BackgroundBitmapImage.Left;
  BackgroundBitmapText.Top := BackgroundBitmapImage.Top + BackgroundBitmapImage.Height + ScaleY(8);
  BackgroundBitmapText.Caption := 'TBitmapImage';
  BackgroundBitmapText.Parent := MainForm;
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first parameter  `wpWelcome` in this case, specifies after witch page our custom page is displayed.

```
Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TButton and others');
```

Comment: Not a very clear answer; this doesn't actually say why the original page doesn't show up, or how to get it back.